# TextView Hyperlink is not working?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, hyperlink

Why `TextView` Hyperlink is not working.

Using hyperlink as inside the custom `dialog box`.

The hyperlink is not appear.

Where i am mistaken. How do solve it. Give me guidance.

XML code is

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/google_Link"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textSize="20dip"
android:linksClickable="true"  
android:autoLink="all"
android:textColorLink="#306EFF"
android:text="" />
```

Android Code is

```
TextView googleLink = ( TextView ) layout.findViewById( R.id.google_Link );
googleLink.setClickable(true);
googleLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
googleLink.setText( Html.fromHtml( "<a href=`http://www.google.co.in`>Google</a>" ) );
```

Android Manifest Code is

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Backticks are not used in HTML for string delimiters. Use `\"` in Java to embed quotation marks inside a quoted string. I would also get rid of `setClickable()` and `setMovementMethod()`, as those should be handled by your proposed `TextView` contents.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace only this link,it will work:

```
TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
textView.setClickable(true);
String linkTxt=getResources().getString(R.string.link);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml( linkTxt));
```

Add this in strings.xml:

```
<string name="link">&lt;a href=http://www.google.co.in&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Best solution to this issue is:
First, create a Textview.

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/link"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:text="@string/developed_by_bracecodes"/>
```

Then add text to your Textview from strings.xml like below:

```
<string name="developed_by_bracecodes"><a href="http://www.bracecodes.com">Developed by Bracecodes</a>  </string>
```

**N.B: don't forget to add http:// before your link**

Then add these lines in your java code:

```
TextView link = findViewById(R.id.link);
link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Happy Coding!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/hyperlink" 
android:text="@string/hyperlink"
android:textColorLink="@color/quantum_yellow"
**android:autoLink="web"**
/>
```

use `autoLink=web` to auto define link text as a clickable hyperlink. You can also decide its color using `textColorLink`

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you can't set a href to a `TextView`.

You'll need to set an OnClickListener which has this in it's `onClick` method:

```
String url = "http://www.google.co.in";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

After that you can set the listener to your `TextView` like this: `googleLink.setOnClickListener(myListener);`

Then run the app again and the click should be handled correctly.

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But the hyperlink is not appear. How do set hyperlink.

Comment: You can use the `setText("http://www.google.co.in")` method of `TextView` for that.

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But when i can use the `setText("Google");` method of `TextView` in that time the hyperlink is not appear.

Comment: How do add my custom title with underline.

Comment: That's a different question. I recommend reading the [documentation for TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) and checking what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is here. https://github.com/saket/Better-Link-Movement-Method

```
implementation 'me.saket:better-link-movement-method:1.1'



 message?.message?.let {
            chatMessageTextView.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(it.trim(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
        }

  chatMessageTextView.movementMethod = BetterLinkMovementMethod.newInstance().apply {
        setOnLinkClickListener { _, url ->
            // Handle click or return false to let the framework handle this link.

       
            handleMessageLink(itemView.context,url)
            true
        }
    }

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_message_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/files_layout"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space_ultra_small"
            android:text="@string/text_small"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:padding="@dimen/space_ultra_small"
            android:textColorLink="@color/sky_blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HtmlTextView extends TextView {
    public HtmlTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HtmlTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public HtmlTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        Spannable spannable = linkifyHtml(String.valueOf(text), Linkify.ALL);
        super.setText(spannable, type);
    }

    private static Spannable linkifyHtml(String html, int linkifyMask) {
        Spanned text = Html.fromHtml(html);
        URLSpan[] currentSpans = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), URLSpan.class);

        SpannableString buffer = new SpannableString(text);
        Linkify.addLinks(buffer, linkifyMask);

        for (URLSpan span : currentSpans) {
            int end = text.getSpanEnd(span);
            int start = text.getSpanStart(span);
            buffer.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

HtmlTextView mText = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
mText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
mText.setText("<a href=`http://www.google.com`>Google");