# How to make XML string resource email clickable with predefined Subject and Body on TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, textview

**[Namaste](https://www.google.com/search?q=namaste&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN912IN912&sxsrf=APq-WBsgAya7uNMhcnwc5B34f2qmPmh_Aw%3A1649080535382&ei=1_hKYpzjFobE4-EPxqqIwAQ&ved=0ahUKEwjcqpHcx_r2AhUG4jgGHUYVAkgQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=namaste&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyBAgjECcyBwgAELEDEEMyCwguEIAEEMcBEK8BMggIABCABBDJAzIFCAAQkgMyCwguEIAEEMcBEK8BMgQIABBDMg0ILhCABBCHAhCxAxAUMggIABCABBCxAzoHCCMQsAMQJzoHCAAQRxCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQzoKCAAQ5AIQsAMYAToMCC4QyAMQsAMQQxgCOg8ILhDUAhDIAxCwAxBDGAJKBAhBGABKBAhGGAFQ-wNYtAtgygxoAXABeACAAYkBiAGMApIBAzAuMpgBAKABAcgBEsABAdoBBggBEAEYCdoBBggCEAEYCA&sclient=gws-wiz)**  to all,

I am trying to achieve a solution where on click of email id in strings XML containing HTML tags we should open Intent Chooser of email apps available in the system, then in the email compose screen **mailTo**, **subject** & the **body** should be populated.

> ```
> to - recipient@xyz.com
> subject - xyz....
> body - xyz.....
> ```

I have tried using **`android:autoLink="email"`** attribute, it is making the email clickable but it only pre-populates the recipient's email id and nothing else.

Is there any other way around to achieve the required solution, without using a third-party library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namaste  to all,

Below is the working solution, without using the `android:autoLink="email"` attribute.

**strings.xml**

> ```
> <string name="str_email_included">Mail us at - &lt;br/> &lt;a href=\'mailto:hello@xyz.com?subject=Subject1&amp;body=Body1\'>hello@xyz.com&lt;/a></string>
> ```

**Java**

> ```
> textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.str_email_included)));
> textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
> ```

**Kotlin**

> ```
> textView.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(getString(R.string.str_email_included), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
> textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
> ```

The above `movementMethod` does the job, so onClick of email id, Intent Chooser will open and the mailTo, subject & body get pre-populated as required.

Comment: Hmmm. A good solution. But, this has a drawback. You cannot add other auto link types without the `android:auto_link="all"` attr

Comment: `textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()` will adapt to **tel:** as well as **mailto:** & for **http/https** also. so it will work for basic problem statement according to requirement

Comment: well. that works for you. that is what we want

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a link as follow:

```
mailto:recipient@xyz.com?subject=xyz subject&body=xyz body
```

This link will open an Intent for Mail application and will contain a prefill subject and body. (Ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/ )

You can have a string as follow:

```xml
<string name="link_str"><a href="mailto:recipient@xyz.com?subject=xyz subject&body=xyz body">Send email</a>  </string>
```

And then make TextView linkable as specified in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49694038/5309486

Comment: Hi Ashok,
I appreciate your input on this , 
I have also posted the somewhat similar but required solution for HTML embedded string resource, which is basically based on `movementMethod` for TextVIew.